# Перевод строки в бинарный код на java

Tags: java

При переводе строки в бинарный код и обратно у меня все работает прекрасно в случае использования латинских символов. В случае перевода кириллицы, перевод в бинарный код срабатывает нормально, но перевод этого же кода обратно в текст не дает изначально введенного слова на кириллице.

```
public class Main {

public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("1. Перевести текст в бинарный код.");
    System.out.println("2. Перевести бинарный код в текст.");
    x = in.nextInt();
    if (x == 1) {
        System.out.println("Введите ниже текст для перевода в бинарный код.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        s = in.nextLine();
        int d[] = new int[255];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            d[i] = Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : s.getBytes()) {
            System.out.print(
                    String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0')
            );
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } else if (x == 2) {
        String str = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите ниже бинарный код.");

        String input = in.nextLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Arrays.stream(
                input.split("(?<=\\G\\d{8})")
        ).forEach(st ->
                sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(st, 2))
        );

        String output = sb.toString();

        Arrays.stream(input.split("(?<=\\G\\d{8})")).forEach(st -> System.out.print((char) Integer.parseInt(st, 2)));
        System.out.print('\n');

    }
}
```

}

[image: текст в бинарный код]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как Вы думаете, сколько байтов занимает кажадая буква в слове "вася"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение моё.

```
public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("1. Перевести текст в бинарный код.");
    System.out.println("2. Перевести бинарный код в текст.");
    x = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    if (x == 1) {
      System.out.println("Введите ниже текст для перевода в бинарный код.");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String s;
      s = in.nextLine();       
      byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
      String bynaryString =
          IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
              .mapToObj(
                  idx ->
                      String.format(
                          "%08d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[idx] & 0xFF))))
              .collect(Collectors.joining());

      System.out.println(bynaryString);

    } else if (x == 2) {
      String str = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Введите ниже бинарный код.");

      String input = in.nextLine();

      Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".{1,8}").matcher(input);
      byte[] backBytes =
          matcher
              .results()
              .mapToInt(
                  result -> Integer.parseInt(input.substring(result.start(), result.end()), 2))
              .collect(
                  ByteArrayOutputStream::new,
                  (baos, i) -> baos.write((byte) i),
                  (baos1, baos2) -> baos1.write(baos2.toByteArray(), 0, baos2.size()))
              .toByteArray();

      String sConverted = new String(backBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

      System.out.printf(sConverted);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я новичок в java поэтому еще многого не знаю. Ваш пример работает отлично!!! Буду разбираться.

Comment: Пользуйтесь на здоровье